# Confidence intervals for sum of n rolls of a biased k-sided die

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I have a distribution that is similar to taking the sum of rolling a possibly biased k-sided die n times. For simplicity, let the die be three sided and let the numbers of the faces of the die be 1, 2 and 3. Lets say i roll this dice 10 times and get the following results: 1 appears 6 times, 2 appears 3 times, 3 appears 1 time, so the sum is 15.

Now from that result i would like to hypothesis test different probability distributions for 10 roll of this dice. For example, $H_0:\bar{x}=16$ (with $H_1:\bar{x}\neq16$) ($\bar{x}$ being the expected value of the sum of 10 rolls). However, I'm not sure how i would run such a hypothesis test. Any suggestions?

Comment: The first step is to articulate a *single* clear hypothesis, because testing multiple hypotheses of this nature would be almost meaningless (and likely quite misleading).  Where do the values of the $p_i$ and $\bar x$ come from?  Do you really only want to test a hypothesis about the mean?

Comment: I've edited the question to better explain $p_1,p_2,p_3,\bar{x}$, and yes i'm only looking to hypothesis test the mean but i am under the belief that different values of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ that share the same mean may not pass the same hypothesis test.

Comment: Please, then, edit your question so that it states your null hypothesis as you intend: namely, $H_0:\, \bar x = 16.$

Comment: As stated previously i'm under the belief that different values of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ that share the same mean may not give the same result (pass/fail) in a hypothesis test, therefore is it not important to state them in the hypothesis test?

Comment: It's not even possible to state them in a legitimate test and still achieve your objective.  Where, for instance, would the specific values of the $p_i$ come from in the statement of the null hypothesis?  You are better off stating what you want to accomplish without imposing restrictions that might make it impossible to succeed.

Comment: You're missing an alternative hypothesis, and it isn't clear if you're looking for the sum of 10 rolls or the average of 10 rolls.  Please revise your question to include these details, else we will have to impute them and that could lead to incorrect suggestions.

Comment: Is thar better?